# Offline Hidden Markov Model for time series analysis

Tags: time-series, hidden-markov-model

One of the main principles of HMM is that the future state is dependent on previous state. This method is widely used for time series segmentation. However, for offline segmentation one can run HMM from past to future and from future to the past. Clearly, the results are direction-dependent (I guess even for symmetric matrix of transitions probabilities).

1. Am I right in thinking that HMM is direction-dependent?
2. If so, is there an improvement of HMM that are free of the
   direction bias?

(I guess it is possible to make a circle from a time series and run several HMMs with different directions, then found true breakpoints as a most supported positions, but it sounds so bad...)

Comment: When you say „time series segmentation“ it makes me think a lot about Bayesian change point detection. Maybe you could use that instead of extending HMMs?